# Cloudfront origin pull from a folder

Tags: dns, amazon-cloudfront

I have setup a CloudFront origin pull server. It allows me to set a domain name, which I have. This works.

But I don't want the whole domain to be the origin. I want

```
mydomain.com/folder/subfolder
```

to be the origin. Also, the cloudfront distribution is CNAMEd to a cdn, which is setup via DNS to cloudfront. This seems to work.

So, basically, instead of this URL:

```
xyz.cloudfront.net/folder/subfolder/1.jpg
```

I want this instead:

```
cdn.mydomain.com/1.jpg
```

Currently I have achieved, via CNAME and origin pull:

```
cdn.mydomain.com/folder/subfolder/1.jpg
```

The question is: on CloudFront how do I setup an origin pull from a folder, not from the main domain name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accepted answer is out of date. This is possible using the "Origin Path" setting in AWS which will rewrite the request to a sub-folder on the origin:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesOriginPath

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Note that this option only *add* a path, it doesn't remove it. For example, you can't request example.com/pro/images/test.jpg and get a file in the S3 bucket example.bucket/images/test.jpg removing '/pro/' path.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of a way to do this cloudfront.  However, you create a virtual host at your origin for subfolder.example.com and have it's root directory be the directory you mentioned.  Then you could set subfolder.example.com as your origin for the default cache behavior.

Comment: While not clean, because this means we'll need a subdomain for each folder we want to cache, this is the right answer for now. Thank you.